# View controller doesn't autorotate to portrait upside down

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, autorotate

I have implemented a view controller just for autorotation. So this view controller, which I called `RotatableViewController`, implements these methods:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

It should autorotate to all orientations, I also have checked the supported interface orientations in my target:

[image]

But incredibly it doesn't autorotate in the portait upside down orientation:

[image]

What could be the problem?

**PS** With iOS 6.1 , the view controller is instantiated through a storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a `UINavigationController`, which does not support up side down by default on iPhones. As a general design principle, iPhone apps should not support upside-down (allegedly because the "lock" switch does lock landscape mode on the iPhone, unlike on the iPad). The upside-down orientation is designed for iPad devices only.

You could solve your problem by subclassing `UINavigationController` and use a `supportedInterfaceOrientations` that returns `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` and specify that as the base class for your navigation controller in the storyboard. But I don't you should be doing that because apps on iPhone should generally not support upside-down portrait orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions had the problem with UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll. Not sure which version you are using. Try redoing with all the orientations.

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Is your viewcontroller wired correctly then?  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;